# How do I capture require errors + error_handlers

Tags: php, exception, error-handling

I am trying to use the `set_error_handler` function to capture `require` errors.
while my custom `error_handler` is being used, the context seems completely off, although the trace is correct.

```
<?php
function error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline){
    throw new Exception($errstr);
}

set_error_handler('error_handler');


try{
    trigger_error("somethign",E_USER_NOTICE);
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo "I got caught";
}


try{
    require "something/that/does/not/exists.php";
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo "I got caught";
}
```

As can be seen, when I trigger the first error, it triggers the `error_handler` which in turn is throwing an exception. Which is caught in the first try-catch.

The second time, where I try to include an un-existing file, again the `error_handler` is used, but the exception is not caught.
What is going on here?

I am using php 5.5.*
Tested in CLI mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the documentation:

> require is identical to include except upon failure it will also
>   produce a fatal E_COMPILE_ERROR level error. In other words, it will
>   halt the script

(http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)

That means, the script execution is aborted when this error is encountered. Your custom error handler will be used but `throw` will be ignore because that assumes further execution which is not allowed at this point.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to remember that there's two general types of errors with PHP

- Processing errors are caught when your program runs
- Compile errors occur when you have bad syntax or when you try to do something impossible

In your case, `require` is a compile error. It will not execute your user defined function because it will never get that far. The compiler can't include the bad file and will fail out.